# export modules to objects, shell script

Tags: javascript, shell, vue.js

I'm working on a Nuxt.js project and the components folder looks like this:

```
/components/atoms/....files.vue
/components/molecules/....files.vue
/components/organisms/....files.vue
/components/templates/....files.vue
```

I need to export the components inside separate objects, example

```
atoms = {all components of the atom folder}
molecules = {all components of the paste of atoms}
organisms = {all components of the atom folder}
templates = {all components of the atom folder}
```

I have a shell that does generate an index.js inside each folder, it follows the code

```
parameters=$(ls components)
for item in ${parameters[*]}
do
    ls components/$item/ | grep -v index.js | sed 's#^\([^.]*\).*$#export {default as \1} from "./&"#' > components/$item/index.js
done
```

result, example

`/components/atoms/index.js`

```
export { default as ButtonStyled } from './ButtonStyled.vue'
export { default as TextLead } from './TextLead.vue'
export { default as InputSearch } from './InputSearch.vue'
....
```

but this does export each component separately, what I need is to export all components inside an object, object with folder name, as exemplified earlier.

The output I need

```
export atoms
export molecules
export organisms
export templates
```

I get the result I need with javascript, however it's a very large and repetitive code.

```
const atoms = {}
const reqAtoms = require.context('@/components/atoms', true, /\.vue$/)
reqAtoms.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, '$1')
  atoms[componentName] = reqAtoms(fileName).default
})

const molecules = {}
const reqMolecules = require.context('@/components/molecules', true, /\.vue$/)
reqMolecules.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, '$1')
  molecules[componentName] = reqMolecules(fileName).default
})

const organisms = {}
const reqOrgarnisms = require.context('@/components/organisms', true, /\.vue$/)
reqOrgarnisms.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, '$1')
  organisms[componentName] = reqOrgarnisms(fileName).default
})

const templates = {}
const reqTemplates = require.context('@/components/templates', true, /\.vue$/)
reqTemplates.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, '$1')
  templates[componentName] = reqTemplates(fileName).default
})

export default {
  atoms,
  molecules,
  organisms,
  templates
}
```

any idea how to do this smaller or do this with shell script?

Thanks for any solution in Shell Script or even in JavaScript.

Comment: `parameters` is not an array, you can't use `${parameters[*]}`.

Comment: It's better to write `for item in components/*`

Comment: See [Why not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: What is the actual output you want?

Comment: @Barmar 
the current code works perfectly, however it is not output I need, I updated my question with the output I need.

Comment: `echo "export $item"` seems like it should do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd use a here-doc as a template, rather than using `sed`.

```
allcomponents=()
for component in components/*
do
    component=${component##*/} # remove directory prefix
    allcomponents+=("$component")
    cat <<EOS
const $component = {}
const req$component = require.context('@/components/$component', true, /\.vue\$/)
req$component.keys().forEach(fileName => {
  const componentName = fileName.replace(/^.+\/([^/]+)\.vue/, '\$1')
  atoms[componentName] = req$component(fileName).default
})

EOS
done > exports.js
echo "export default {" >> exports.js
printf "  %s,\n" "${allcomponents[@]}" >> exports.js
echo "}" >> exports.js
```

Comment: Sorry, this simply writes in my terminal `export atoms`, `export molecules` ..... I need a real export, a final javascript file exporting an object with all components of the folder inside

Comment: Redirect the output to a filename

Comment: As I mentioned in my question `atoms = {all components of the atom folder}`

Comment: That's not what you said in the question. Show what the actual file contents should be.

Comment: You wrote that the output you need is `export atoms`.

Comment: look at my question now please.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193846/discussion-between-yung-silva-and-barmar).

Comment: erro line 17: %: syntax error: operand expected (error token is "%").

Comment: Sorry, made a typo, `[%]` should be `[@]`

Comment: Where does export.js go?

Comment: Whereever you want the result of this to go. I just picked an arbitrary name, you can call it whatever you want.

Comment: This should just create a file that looks like the output you said you want.

Comment: Thanks for the help, you're very good at shell script, I command very badly ...

but the code was executed without errors but did not generate any files, in any directory, would you be able to make explicit the output directory of the file, like my old shell script?

Comment: It should create a file in the current directory. The contents of that file should look exactly like what you wrote after "I got the result I needed with JavaScript".

Comment: I'm confused about what you want. Do you want one file like the final result you show, or a separate file in each component directory?

Comment: I need a file with the final code, I found the file export.js, its oks.

when I run the [code](https://image.prntscr.com/image/fIH37OgMTtiia8Sl9O_PIA.png), I get the `export.js` file with the [result](https://image.prntscr.com/image/8O7E-GTvQIe0QBg8oIYkiA.png), but the constants name is wrong, needs to be without 
 `components/`, [same in the image](https://image.prntscr.com/image/8O7E-GTvQIe0QBg8oIYkiA.png)

Comment: Fixed it. `${component##/}` should have been `${component##*/}`